# Can a batsman's score be predicted in the sport of cricket?

Tags: reference-request, statistics, soft-question

I was browsing [*The Signal and the Noise*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159420411X) in bookstore and chanced upon a chapter about predictions in baseball and found out about *Moneyball* and [sabermetrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabermetrics). I understand the closest to predicting a cricket match score comes via [Duckworth-Lewis method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duckworth%E2%80%93Lewis_method) and [Jayadevan's system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VJD_System) but going over these two following references: ([1](http://www.jssm.org/vol5/n4/3/v5n4-3text.php)) ([2](http://www.scribd.com/doc/76403294/Time-Series))  no work was found on an *individual's innings*.

Probably this question is too soft for this site, but problem is I have basically no knowledge about statistics and I do not know what to search for to find out how bettors use algorithms to predict scores. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to add [this link](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/543061.html) which was a further inspiration for the question.

Comment: Who would have predicted that Bradman, with his 100 average, would end his career with a duck? Anyway, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8Tiba3h9Fw might interest you.